# Inequality regarding LCM of $1, 2, \ldots, n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, alternative-proof

While going through F. Beukers proof of irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ I found the inequality $d_{n} < 3^{n}$ for all sufficiently large values of $n$ where $d_{n}$ denotes the LCM of all the numbers $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n$

Now this is easily established (almost obvious) once one assumes the prime number theorem. In fact we can replace $3^{n}$ by  $a^{n}$ where $a > e$.

I would like to know if there is any elementary/direct proof of $d_{n} < 3^{n}$ without the recourse to the difficult prime number theorem.

Comment: $\mbox{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots,n)$ is [Landau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function) $g(n)$.
It can be shown that $g(n)<e^{n/e}$. Since $e^{n/e} < 3^n$, we have $g(n) < 3^n$.

Comment: Note also that 
$$
d_n = d_{n-1} \cdot \begin{cases}
p & \text{if } n = p^k \text{ for some } k\geq 1,\ p\in\mathbb{P} \\
1 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851328 Interestingly, proving a lower bound seems to be easier than proving an upper bound. Which is also the case in Chebyshev's original proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An elementary proof of that $d_n=\mbox{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots,n)<3^n$
can be found in this article by D. Hanson:
[On the product of the primes](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/EBCBB4096EBC2A145C743C4C0E123E69/S0008439500060835a.pdf/on_the_product_of_the_primes.pdf), Canad. Math. Bull. 15(1972), 33-37. The same paper on [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267137759_On_the_product_of_the_primes).

Comment: The link which you have referred doesn't work :(

Comment: @crskhr I edited the link with a new one. You can also try https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267137759_On_the_product_of_the_primes

Comment: Thanks, though not much i could comprehend, i am sure it was useful edit for the users.