# Finding the product of a prime function...

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, intuition, products

If we take the primes $p_k < n$, and raise them to the highest power possible such that $(p_k)^{r_k} \le n$, what is the lower bounds on $\prod{ (p_k)^{r_k} }$?  In other words, what are the asymptotics of this function?

For example, if $n=10$, $2^3 \le 10$, $3^2 \le 10$, $5^1 \le 10$, and $7^1 \le 10$.  This product is $2^3 3^2 5^1 7^1 = 2520$.  So the function at $10$ is $2520$.  Again, how closely can we bound this function?

Comment: You have a guaranteed factor of $n$#, followed by $\sqrt n$#, followed by $\sqrt[3]{n}$#, etc.  Not sure this is bound-able though.

Comment: Note that $lcm(1,2,\ldots,n)=2520$ for $n=10$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Yes, I believe that the number is guaranteed to be $\text{lcm}\left( \sum_{k=1}^n k \right)$

Comment: I've found this question: math.stackexchange.com/questions/998922/bounds-for-lcm1-dots-n  If someone can prove that the product in this question is equivalent to the lcm(1,2,3,...,n) I will accept their answer.

Comment: Strongly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998922/bounds-for-lcm1-dots-n, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834220/least-common-multiple-lim-sqrtn1-2-dotsc-n-e

Comment: You miswrote it, but yes, your function is $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\ldots,n)$.

Comment: @6005: Yes, I realized I miswrote it, but I thought I'd keep the comment, hoping that everyone had the idea.  Anyways, thanks for the links - they do help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Chebyshev $\psi\left(x\right)
 $ function [is defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) as $$\psi\left(n\right)=\sum_{p^{k}\leq n}\log\left(p\right)
 $$ where the sum is for all powers of prime less or equal than $x
 $. It is well known that $$\psi\left(n\right)=e^{\textrm{lcm}\left(1,2,\dots,n\right)}.
 $$ Let $m\left(p\right)$ the maximum power of $p
 $ such that $p^{m\left(p\right)}\leq n$. Then is sufficient to note that $$m\left(p\right)=\left\lfloor \log_{p}\left(n\right)\right\rfloor 
 $$ hence our product is $$\log\left(\prod_{p\leq n}p^{m\left(p\right)}\right)=\sum_{p\leq n}m\left(p\right)\log\left(p\right)
 $$ $$=\sum_{p\leq n}\left\lfloor \log_{p}\left(n\right)\right\rfloor \log\left(p\right)=\psi\left(n\right)
 $$ so $$\prod_{p\leq n}p^{m\left(p\right)}=e^{\psi\left(n\right)}=\textrm{lcm}\left(1,2,\dots,n\right).$$ Using the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) we know that $$\psi\left(n\right)\sim n
 $$ so we have the asymptotic $$\prod_{p\leq n}p^{m\left(p\right)}\sim e^{n}.$$