# Prove $4^m < \operatorname{lcm} (m+1, m+2, \dots, 2m+1)$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, least-common-multiple

I was looking at review sheet for my midterm for primality testing and factorization and saw this on it

$$4^m < \operatorname{lcm} (m+1, m+2, \dots, 2m+1)$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: Use the facts that $a\cdot b=\gcd(a,b)\cdot \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ and that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\gcd(n,n+1)=1$

Comment: My first guess would be to look at some central binomial coefficients $2n \choose n$

Comment: The central binomial coefficient method tends to give upper bounds of the form $4^m$ rather than lower bounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that for $k\leq m$ we have $nk\in\{m+1,\ldots,2m+1\}$ for some $n\geq2$. This imply
$$
\text{lcm} \{m+1,\ldots,2m+1\}=\text{lcm}\{m,m+1,\ldots,2m+1\}=\text{lcm}\{m-1,m,m+1,\ldots,2m+1\}=\cdots=\text{lcm}\{1,2,\ldots,2m+1\}.
$$

Now we can use that $\text{lcm}\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\geq 2^n$ if $n\geq7$, whose proof you can find in [this excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851328/textlcm1-2-3-ldots-n-geq-2n-for-n-geq-7) by @shadow10, to conclude
$$
\text{lcm}\{m+1,\ldots,2m+1\}\geq 2^{2m+1}=2\cdot4^m>4^m, \hspace{.2cm}m>2.
$$
The cases $m=0,1,2$ can be checked by hand.

Comment: "Notice that for $k \leq m$ we have $2k \in \{m+1, \dots, 2m+1\}$" - Should $2k$ be a more general $nk$ instead?

Comment: Why? Clearly $\text{lcm}\{k,m+1,m+2,\ldots,2m+1\}\geq\text{lcm}\{m+1,m+2,\ldots,2m+1\}$. The condition $2k\in\{m+1,\ldots,2m+1\}$ tells you that this inequality is actually an equality. @HarrySmit

Comment: Ohhh! Yes, I see your point. Will fix it. Thank u! :)@HarrySmit

Comment: Everything seems to be correct now. :)