# Comparing the Least Common Multiple for $n!$ to the square root of $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, factorial, least-common-multiple

I have been thinking about the [Least Common Multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) and how it compares to $n!$

> For $n=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, the lcm for $n!$ is greater than $\sqrt{n!}$.

Is this always the case?

I would be interested in understanding how to analyze this.

Here's the thinking about this that I've done to this point:

> Let $v(p,n)$ be the highest power of $p$ that is less or equal to $n$.
>
> The least common multiple for $n!$ is:
>
> $$\prod\limits_{p \le n}p^{v(p,n)}$$

I find it is much easier to reason about $\frac{(x+n)!}{x!}$ where I find in all cases:

> $$\frac{(x+n)!}{x!\prod\limits_{p \le n}p^{v(p,x+n)}} \le (n-1)!$$

But applying this to the case of $n!$ is not interesting:

> $$\frac{n!}{\prod\limits_{p \le n}p^{v(p,n)}} \le (n-1)!$$

- the lcm of $n!$ increases each time a higher power or a prime is encountered.
- Primes get rarer as $n$ increases.
- Larger powers of primes also get rarer as $n$ increases.

What method would be used to compare the lcm of $n!$ with $\sqrt{n!}$?  Under what conditions would the lcm of $n!$ be less than $\sqrt{n!}$?

Comment: The Prime number theorem is equivalent to $(\operatorname{lcm}(1,\ldots,n))^{1/n}\to e$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851328

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L_n=\text{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n)$. Then $\ln L_n=\psi(n)$ where
$$\psi(n)=\sum_{p\le n}\left\lfloor\frac{\ln n}{\ln p}\right\rfloor\ln p.$$
It is well-known that the Prime Number Theorem implies $\psi(n)\sim n$.
By Stirling $\log\sqrt{n!}$ grows faster. Eventually $L_n<\sqrt{n!}$
for all large $n$.

Comment: Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962) Theorem 12, for $x > 0$   we have $\psi(x) < 1.03883 x.$ The maximum of $\psi(x) /x$ is achieved at $x = 113.$