# How might I prove that LCM$(m) \geq 2^m$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, least-common-multiple

Denoting by LCM$(m)$ the lowest common multiple of the first $m$ numbers, can anyone suggest a way in which I might prove that, for $m \geq 7$,
$$
\text{LCM}(m) \geq 2^m
$$

I believe that a proof of this may be found within the proof of Theorem 2 of the paper 'On Chebyshev-Type Inequalities for Primes' by M. Nair, but I am currently struggling to follow this.

Comment: Counterexample: LCM(3)=6, which is less than 2^3. There are more (LCM(4), LCM(6), ...)

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention that $m \geq 7$. I have amended the question now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851328/textlcm1-2-3-ldots-n-geq-2n-for-n-geq-7