# Question about integration by parts as used in a previous answer on MSE.

Tags: integration, binomial-coefficients, proof-explanation, least-common-multiple

I was reading through this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/851411/48606) to a question about the lower bound of a [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).

The question is about showing that:

$$\text{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n) > 2^n$$

I was not clear on one step in the answer provided.

Here are the steps that I understand:

(1) I am clear on the definition of $I_{m,n}$ where $1 \le m \le n$:

> $$I_{m,n}=\int_0^1x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-m}dx = \sum_{r=0}^{n-m}\frac{a_r}{m+r}$$
> where each $a_r \in \mathbb{Z}$

(2) I am clear that if $\displaystyle\ell_n = \text{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n)$ that:

> $$\displaystyle\ell_n I_{m,n} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

I am unclear when [Integration by Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) is applied.

(3) The answer states:

> Now it can easily be seen that $I_{m,n} = \dfrac{1}{m{n\choose m}}$
>
> Which follow from integration by parts or reduction formulae.

Could someone explain to me how this last step follows from the first two?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the integral can be written as the beta function, which can be written in terms of the gamma function, which can be written in terms of factorials

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'm not familiar with the beta function.  I'll review.  I am familar with the gamma function.  If you can write the equality as the answer, I will be glad to review and accept if it is clear to me.

Comment: @seth.  Cool stuff:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Thanks.  I'll update the question so it is correct and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I_{m,n}=\int_0^1 x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-m+1-1}dx=B(m,n-m+1)=\cfrac{\Gamma(m) \Gamma(n-m+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}$, which, if n and m are positive integers, is equal to $\cfrac{(m-1)!(n-m)!}{n!}=\cfrac{1}{m{n \choose m}}$, as claimed

Comment: Thanks very much!  I'll check if I made a typo.  I linked to the original answer that I was quoting.

Comment: Yes, I checked the link, you put the terminals the wrong way around. It's a pretty minor thing, and it was still easy to understand your question

Comment: Thanks!  I updated the question so that it is correct.  I appreciate your answer.